# Streaming a large remote file

Tags: node.js, express

I need to serve local files from a different server using node. The api endpoint are being handled by express.

The goal is not to contain the entire file in memory instead stream the data so it shows the output to the enduser progressively.

By reading the [stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) api documentation i came up with this solution with a combination with expressjs response. Here is the example:

```js
  const open = (req, res) => {
    const formattedUrl = new url.URL(
      "https://dl.bdebooks.com/Old%20Bangla%20Books/Harano%20Graher%20Jantra%20Manob%20-%20Shaktimoy%20Biswas.pdf"
    );
    const src = fs.createReadStream(formattedUrl);
    return src.pipe(res);
  };
```

But when i hit this express endpoint `http://localhost:3000/open` it throws following error:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL_SCHEME]: The URL must be of scheme file

I would like to display the file content inline! What I am doing wrong? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: `formattedUrl` is an object. You need to use [`formattedUrl.toString()`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_tostring) to get the actual URL string

Comment: @Seblor That yield `The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL`

Comment: Yes, that's because `fs` is a module that interacts with the file system, not the internet. You need to make an http(s) request for that

Comment: `fs.createReadStream()` does NOT accept an http/https URL.  Use `http.get()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.createReadStream()` operates on the file system.  It does not accept an `http` or `https` URL.  Instead, you need to use something like `http.get()` to make an http request and then return a readable stream that you can then pipe from.

```
const open = (req, res) => {
  const formattedUrl = new url.URL("https://dl.bdebooks.com/Old%20Bangla%20Books/Harano%20Graher%20Jantra%20Manob%20-%20Shaktimoy%20Biswas.pdf");
  http.get(formattedUrl, (stream) => {
      stream.pipe(res);
  }).on('error', (err) => {
      // send some sort of error response here
  });
};
```